# I need to provide a user logoff option in php

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to php and server-side scripting languages all together. I have a website and I am developing a members section. My issue is I can't seem to get the user logged off. Is there something I am over-looking. I have done research and this is the implementation I am using:

```
<?php // this is the start-up php on all member only pages
session_name('name');
session_set_cookie_params(0); //set to delete upon browser close



 // this is the code to set the log off, with a redirect to index page

 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header("Location: http://foo"); 
 ?>
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <Title>Log-Out Redirect</title>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Use `session_start();` only once.

Comment: It's actually a good practice to start a new session and immediately destroy it, specially on sites that do the login and logout in the same script.

Comment: Another thing, it's `<!doctype html>` and not just `<!doctype>`

Comment: Plus, you can use `unset($_SESSION);` or more specifically for a user `unset($_SESSION['username']);` then `session_destroy();` and checking if the session is set or not. I.e. `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){...}` for each page.

Comment: Thanks I actually just ran it through and it worked, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach like this may work (if the *login* and *logout* is performed in the same script):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $loggedIn = false;

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
        if (isset($_POST['logout_intent') && $_POST['logout_intent'] == true)
            session_destroy();
        else
            $loggedIn = true;
    else {
        if (isset($_POST['login_intent'] && $_POST['login_intent'] == true) {
            /* Try to make the login and set your variables accordingly */
            if ($loginSuccess)
                $loggedIn = true;
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            else 
                $loggedIn = false;
        }

    }
?>
```

Later in your code...

```
<?php
    if ($loggedIn) {
        /* 
        * Show admin panels or whatever a logged in user must see,
        * like a logout button; e.g...
        */
        echo 
        '<form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout">
            <input type="hidden" name="logout_intent" value="true">
        <logout>';
    } else {
        /* 
        * Show whatever a non-logged in user must see, like a
        * login or register form; e.g...
        */
        echo 
        '<form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <input type="hidden" name="login_intent" value="true">
        <logout>';
    }
?>
```

Note that a blank action parameter value means that it'll send data to the same page as the one the form is in.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect your use, try to use :

```
<?php header("Location: http://foo"); ?>
```

You can you relative or absolute links.

Answer (score 0):

try this i am not sure on it

unset($_SESSION['session_value']);